# Issues with rails, postgres, timezones and scopes

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, named-scope

We're seeing some funky stuff when trying to do scopes in Rails 3 in regards to timezones.  Let's say we have an attribute called start_at of type date time.  In application.rb we have `config.time_zone = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'` set based on our server location.

When someone sets start_at to something like '2014-02-22 at 7pm EST' in the db it's stored as '2014-02-23 01:00:00-5' so when I setup a named scope such as:

```
scope :tomorrow, where("start_at = ?", Date.tomorrow)
```

that record is wrongly returned.  If I try something like this:

```
scope :tomorrow, where("start_at at time zone 'EST' = ?", Date.tomorrow)
```

it still doesn't work.  How can I create scopes with db date time comparisons that account for the local timezone without having to do something ridiculous, such as:

```
scope :tomorrow, where("date(start_at - INTERVAL '5 hours') = ?", Date.tomorrow)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the Time.zone option to use the zone that you configured

```
scope :tomorrow, where("start_at = ?", Time.zone.today + 1)
```

I recommend this good article about [Rails time zones](http://danilenko.org/2012/7/6/rails_timezones/)